# Two Tomcat SSL Providers & One FreeBSD

Tags: ssl, tomcat, freebsd

Versions used:

1. JDK 1.6
2. Apache Tomcat 6.0.2X
3. CryptoPro CSP 3.6 provider (www.cryptopro.ru)

Question: On FreeBSD8 I need to have two opened HTTPS different ports (443 and 444, for example). In other words, I need two providers, working simultaneously:

1. Ordinary SSL signed certificate (# Thawte) on 443 port
2. Special russian security provider (# DIGTProvider, based on CryptoPro CSP software) on 444 port

I also have to mentioned, that the major provider is the 2'nd provider. Here is some of *DIGTProvider* options:

- add to ${JRE_HOME}/lib/security/java.security this line

  security.provider.N=com.digt.trusted.jce.provider.DIGTProvider
  ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.digt.trusted.jsse.provider.DigtSocketFactory
- uncomment and edit in conf/server.xml HTTPS section:

  sslProtocol="GostTLS" (added)
- edit bin/catalina.sh and add:

  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/cprocsp/lib/ia32"

  export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.digt.trusted.jsse.server.certFile=/home//server-gost.cer -Dcom.digt.trusted.jsse.server.keyPasswd=11111111"

As I know if I just define in *server.xml* tomcat's configuration file two SSL connectors, tomcat would not start, because in JRE you can use only one JSSE provider.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question a bit. What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? What's the exact error message you get? What versions of java/tomcat are you using?

Comment: @pehrs: hi, here is the link of solved solution, but it's only for windows systems - http://serverfault.com/questions/117740/running-two-independent-tomcats-on-one-machine-instead-of-one-tomcat-with-multip . I'm trying to do the same things on freebsd. Just for now, there is no error messages or warning, because I'm trying to do it right now. Versions I added to top post. Thanks.

Comment: @all: may be there will be more questions? %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: do two copies of tomcat6 dist, and configure one with *Ordinary SSL signed certificate* and another one with *Special russian security provider*.